# How do you make visual studio professional show the files in the same folders that they're actually in inside of the solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-project

I used file>new>project from existing code

In the Solution Explorer instead of showing the files in the folders they're actually in, it shows them in folders named External Dependencies, Header Files, Resource Files, and Source Files.

How do I change this so that visual studio actually shows the file system as it actually is rather than this arbitrary setup it has given the files?